Spring Cloud Config server and composite configuration
I have a microservice platform.
Assume in contains 4 services: meta-service, cool-service, nice-service, notsocool-service.
There are 3 major parts of configuration: shared part (common for all 4), individual configurations unique for each service, shared external connection settings required by some of the services.
Config files that I currently have:
application.properties # shared configuration
meta-service.properties
cool-service.properties
nice-service.properties
notsocool-service.properties
postgres.properties # PG connection info & settings
kafka.properties # Kafka connection info & settings

I'd like the services to load these properties from the config server as follows:
meta-service: application.properties, meta-service.properties
cool-service: application.properties, cool-service.properties, kafka.properties
nice-service: application.properties, nice-service.properties, postgres.properties
notsocool-service: application.properties, notsocool-service.properties, kafka.properties, postgres.properties

How do I approach it? I've tried different ways, but the config server does not even load anything but application.properties
Does Config Server even allow this or does it require {application} name for every config that is not application.properties (i.e. globally shared config)?
